# What is the difference between "go in to work" and "go to work"

Tags: prepositions, difference, phrase-meaning

What is the difference between **"go in to work"** and **"go to work"**?

Initially, I stumbled on **go in to work** watching Big Bang Theory movie series, an episode where Sheldon got fired, and Penny asked him

> How come you didn't go in to work today?

But after I try to google it I found that both expressions seem to be quite common though scrutinizing of those google hits doesn't help me to understand a difference in using. Meanings of both seem to be the same to me.

Comment: [American English!](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2151922/Dont-talk-garbage--American-words-mangling-English.html) :D

Comment: Really, so easy? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Go in to work** has a very specific meaning that implies physically travelling to one's place of business.

**Go to work** can be used in place of **Go in to work**, but it may also be used to imply focusing one's attention on a task. For example, one may **Go to work** on a taco if one is very hungry and the taco is very large. This usage could also be expressed as **Get to work**, which oddly enough rarely refers to arriving at a place of business; almost always referring to focusing on a task or responsibility.